# Squid max number of ips limited to 128

Tags: linux, configuration, centos6, squid

I'm having a problem finding a solution to a problem I am having with my squid proxy server. I am using centos 6.7 with the latest version of squid for my OS. I am pretty sure this is more of a linux issue but there could be a squid setting I haven't found yet, but basically when I configure squid I use include files for each ip/port configuration. So inside my squid.conf file, I add one line to include all files in one of my subdirectories, like:

include /etc/squid/ips/*.conf

and my files look like this:
acl proxyport3128 myportname 3128 src 0.0.0.0/32
http_access allow proxyport3128
tcp_outgoing_address x.x.x.x proxyport3128
http_port x.x.x.x:3128 name=3128

This works fine, I even am able to use ipv6 as the outgoing address, no problems there, but if I add more than 128 files to that directory, or even create 1 file for all of the above configs, it will accept the first 128 it finds and ignore all the rest, no errors, like the ip configs are not even there.

I have seen a similar linux issue to this when trying to add more than a certain number of ipv6 addresses to the same server, in that case I had to change a setting inside /etc/sysctl.conf, my gut is telling me there may be a setting in either that config file or somewhere else that I don't know about.

If there is a work around please share, otherwise I can look in to the multi instance way of using squid (know nothing about it yet), or rotating config files and reloading squid. Multiple tcp_outgoing_addresses might also help the problem, but it's more me wanting to understand the limitation and whether it's squid or linux causing the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and after some research I found out the solution, however it comes with a cost. First thing first yes there is a limit of 128 connections. Let me quote

> For each packet read Squid has to check the listening port list to see
>   if it is a read() or accept() operation. Doing even 128 checks per
>   packet is pushing the boundaries for reasonable performance loss.

So that's why the limit is there. If you want to remove it well you can do it by building the latest version of Squid using: 
`./configure CXXFLAGS="-DMAXTCPLISTENPORTS=XXX"`
where XXX is your new limit

Answer based on:
http://squid-web-proxy-cache.1019090.n4.nabble.com/squid-with-multiple-ips-is-listenting-to-some-ips-with-port-and-not-all-of-ips-td4668784.html